# Android studio how build all gradle buildTypes

Tags: android, gradle

I have four entries in buildTypes. It's working fine, I can trigger gradle build command on linux terminal, in project dir, 8 apk files are created etc. In android studio I can switch between build variants and run selected variant on device.

Question is: how can I build all variants from android studio level? It there possibility to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Gradle tool window, and under the "All tasks" section, choose the "assemble" task.

Comment: Yep, that's it, I'm blind :P.